# Isn't a std::string a std::vector<char>?

Tags: c++, string, vector, stl

In c++ primer 5th, 9.2.5. Assignment and swap, I read about this:

> The fact that elements are not moved means that, with the exception of
>   string, iterators, references, and pointers into the containers are
>   not invalidated. They refer to the same elements as they did before
>   the swap.

So, why is string a exception? I always think that string is a vector, isn't that true?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The very wording you cite demonstrates that strings aren't vectors. When you swap two vectors, iterators remain valid and point into the new vectors. There is no analogous requirement on strings. This allows strings to use small-buffer optimizations.

It may be more appropriate to compare `basic_string` and `vector`, because those are both templates that are parametrized on element type and allocator. This shows further differences: `basic_string` may only be specialized for literal types. And `basic_string` also takes a third parameter, the traits, which determine how comparison is done.

What strings have in common with vectors is that they store the data contiguously.

Comment: I think vector and basic_string both use pointer to point to the data area, so  the only effective way to implement the swap is to swap the pointer pointing to the contiguous data area like vector, isn't it?

Comment: @cong: To repeat: There is no such requirement on strings. The only requirement is that data be stored contiguously. Look up the small-buffer optimization, which does *not* use a separate data area and thus cannot be "swapped", but instead requires copying of the data.

Comment: Ok, I may check the source when I'm able to.

Answer (score 4):

`std::string` is *not* a `std::vector`. It's a [std::basic_string](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string).

Comment: Then how is std::basic_string implemented? is std::basic_string a container?

Comment: It's usually not thought of as a container in my experience, but it *is* a container of characters so I guess you can think of it that way. As for implementation; you could go take a look at the standard library source from gcc or clang.

Comment: @cong: No, basic_string is *not* a container. Don't think of it as a container. It has shares some properties with containers, but it differs in others.

Answer (score 2):

`std::string` is defined in header [`<string>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/string) as a template like this:

```
template< 
    class CharT, 
    class Traits = std::char_traits<CharT>, 
    class Allocator = std::allocator<CharT>
> class basic_string;
```

But [vector](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) is defined differently:

```
template<
    class T,
    class Allocator = std::allocator<T>
> class vector;
```

So `std::string` and `vector<char>` are not the same.

They are implemented differently.

Comment: Could you tell me the implementation of swap for basic_string in a easy-to-understand way? It's a little difficult for me to read the stl source code.

Comment: There is a simple example included in the documentation: [std::basic_string::swap](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/swap)

Comment: I can totally understand that example, What I really want to know is why the implementation of swap for string is not the same as vector which just swap the pointer pointing to the data area.